Media Library it doesn't show any of the uploaded images after updating wordpress 6.6.2
I have this problem since wordpress was automatically updated by whm/wp-toolkit.
I continued to use the "Media Sync" plugin to return the images to the "Media Library" and it works. So now the images are back in the "Media Library". So "Media Sync" after returning the image to the Media Library does not return it to the Featured Image according to what is uploaded in each post.

But now the images in the posts do not appear on the Site/Featured. There is no error that the image is missing from the frontend.

1). I changed the theme and disabled the plugin. permalink, flush media.
2). I downgraded wordpress to 6.6.1,
3). I cleared the cache and disabled the firewall in whm.
4). I also checked the wp_postmeta/wp_posts database, the images are there with the correct url.
After editing a post i get this message:


"wp-json/wp/v2/media/1142808?context=view&_locale=user 404 (Not Found)" and the image is not found within that post.
r/Wordpress - Missing featured image
Missing featured image
r/Wordpress - wp-json/wp/v2/media
wp-json/wp/v2/media
All this happened 3 days ago on the day WP/6.6.2 was launched.
Do you have any advice on what else to do?

After a thorough inspection of the database, i saw that the post_type for the images had changed to "post" instead of "attachment".
The solution Update Post mime type from "post_status = inherit" sql:
// Mime type - img/jpeg
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_type = 'attachment' WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'inherit' and wp_posts.post_mime_type = 'image/jpeg';
// Mime type - img/png
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_type = 'attachment' WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'inherit' and wp_posts.post_mime_type = 'image/png';
// Mime type - img/webp
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_type = 'attachment' WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'inherit' and wp_posts.post_mime_type = 'image/webp';
// Mime type - video/mp4
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_type = 'attachment' WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'inherit' and wp_posts.post_mime_type = 'video/mp4';
